# What could be the better to focus on the item that was open earlier when we do click on back button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a listing page in react js, that lazy loads when we do reach the end of the page, like all ecommerce sites or any other sites load. When I do open product detail page of any of the product item and come back by clicking back button, it doesn't land me to the same product in listing, except this it again hit the API and load the first ten product only.

What I have tried so far is tried to save all the fetched data in redux saga and fetch it condition base, like if I have data in redux then it'll fetch initial data from then otherwise hit the API. But I found this step a bit time taking, especially when I do save hundered and thousands of list item. I want to list the data as quick as it come back.

Althoug this works only if I do click on the button that I have created on Product detail page, if I comeback from the back button, in the browser, then this thing doesn't work.

Is there any other workaround that can be much more effective??

Comment: 1 possible solution is to use URL fragments and have your product fragment as unique id, as soon you click back button from browser, if it's fragment exists in DOM, it automatically navigate to that particular section

Comment: You can use react-query easily for caching the data ....

Comment: That I'm doing right now, Passing the id of the item and assign the id to the key so it can focus the item itself @amansinghgusain.

Comment: I'm doing it with redux for now, Is react query faster or redux?? @Sektowr

Comment: @JayantSingh are you using URL fragments?

Comment: So, when you click back button on browser, your redux data is not being loaded?

Comment: Not actually. I'm getting id and focusing it using javascript @amansinghgusain

Comment: But there is a catch with url fragmentation. As I'm loading data from redux, will this still work, as the content may not be loaded at the time of page load?? @amansinghgusain

Comment: @JayantSingh basically you would need to deferred fragment load, when you sucessfully load data from redux, use scrollIntoView function ex: `document.querySelector("#yourUniqueId").scrollIntoView()`

Comment: @amansinghgusain that's I'm doing alreadt